# .htaccess file isn't working for https

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, https

I have simple .htaccess file to forbid access to a directory as :

```
order allow,deny 
deny from all
```

Well, it doesn't work with SSL and show the content of directory if client access the directory like https://some-url-here.com/forbidden-directory

Comment: How is your SSL vhost configured? You'll need to reflect changes in the configuration you did for the non-SSL version to the SSL version as well (or put it into a separate file referenced in both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specify that .htaccess is allowed to override directives.

Check [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and make sure it is correctly defined in your virtual host definition.

Answer (score 0):

gtirloni and SvW have already gave the answer but even though I will give more direct answer to make it easier for other starter level developers to save their time.

SSL configuration file is located in : 
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl

"< Directory /var/www/ >" section in my file looked like this before :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

All I had to do was to change the "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All". So .htaccess files will not be ignored anymore for SSL.

So fixed version looks like this :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for complementing the answer. Just a heads up, "AllowOverride All" will allow .htaccess to override, well, everything. This can be dangerous. I understand you focused on starter level developers, but a sysadmin will want to do a more fine grained configuration. In this case, using "AllowOverride Limit" might be a better choice, so only "Order" and "Deny" can be used in htaccess. I understand my answer was lacking and thank you again for improving it.